# Error when trying to "where" on strongly typed list, error CS0103

Tags: c#, linq, join

I've got linq which joins two lists by id and returns strongly typed List:

```
   List<TestowaKlasaDlaLinq> linqlambda = ListDetailedData.Join(PlacesList, a => a.place.id, b => b.id, (a, b) =>
                new TestowaKlasaDlaLinq()
                {
                    Czas = a.startDate.TimeOfDay.ToString(),
                    Co = a.name,
                    Miasto = b.address.city,
                    Miejsce = a.organizer.designation
                }).ToList();
```

For now everything works. Problem appeared when I tried to filter that list e.g.:

```
   var onlyGdansk = linqlambda.Where(x => x.Miasto.Equals("Gdańsk")).Select(x => x).ToList();
```

That error came out:
[image]

How is this possible that strongly field of strongly typed List of type "TestowaKlasaDlaLinq" doesnt exist in that context?

Comment: that should work - do you have a typo somehwere?

Comment: No I do not have.

Comment: Just to check, try this :    var onlyGdansk = linqlambda.Where(tkdl => tkdl.Miasto.Equals("Gdańsk")).Select(dl => dl).ToList();

Comment: @GaurangDave Stilll System.NullReferenceException.

Comment: I think, One of the x.Miasto value is null and that is the reason, it shows you this error.  Try var ar onlyGdansk = linqlambda.Where(tkdl => tkdl.Miasto!=null && tkdl.Miasto.Equals("Gdańsk")).Select(dl => dl).ToList();

Comment: @GaurangDave That was the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: @needtobe : Most of the exceptions (90%) are null check exception only. Check null values properly. I put the same as answer below. Please accept it and upvote if it is useful. Thanks. :)

Comment: If you're getting a null reference exception then that's what you should mention in the question, not what I'm guessing are some odd ball errors while debugging.

Comment: `a.Equals(b)` should b avoided in C#.  If the type is known at compiletime us `==`, if it's only known at runtime use `Equals(a, b)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, One of the x.Miasto value is null and that is the reason, it shows you this error.

```
var onlyGdansk = linqlambda.Where(tkdl => tkdl.Miasto!=null && tkdl.Miasto.Equals("Gdańsk")).Select(dl => dl).ToList();
```

Comment: You can simplify it a bit more: `tkdl.Miasto?.Equals("Gdańsk") == true`. Also worth mentioning that `.Select(dl => dl)` does nothing and therefore is redundant here

Answer (score 0):

A variant of Gauran Dave's answer: do not put the Equals function on the string in property `Miasto`, because that string could be null, but put the Equals function on the string "Gdańsk". You may be assert that "Gdańsk" is not null.

```
var onlyGdansk = linqlambda.Where(x => "Gdańsk".Equals(x)))
    .Select(x => x) // this one can be omitted
    .ToList();
```

Or consider using [String.Equals(string, string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hkt4325(v=vs.110).aspx), which IMHO is a bit more readable here:

```
var onlyGdansk = linqlambda.Where(x => String.Equals(x, "Gdańsk"))
    .Select(x => x) 
    .ToList()
```

Comment: That's even better. Thanks.